# ant - compare two lists

Tags: ant

How to compare two lists in ant? Basically I am getting all the message_id's from the database for all my id's and want to compare them to the same id's after some messages in database are deleted.

Comment: It depends.  You might be able to use [conditions](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html), but it would be easier to help if you said what the lists look like (comma separated values in a string?) what type of difference result you want (comma-sep list of ids for messages that have been deleted?) and what you want to do with the list.

Answer (score 2):

A very simple one assuming the lists are exactly identical in num of lines, charcters, whitespace etc., this would yield a match, else the property will not be set.

```
<condition property="comp" value="the files match">   
<filesmatch file1="a.txt" file2="b.txt"/> 
</condition> 

<echo> !!!! </echo>
<echo> ${comp}</echo>
<echo> !!!! </echo>
```